# Generating custom elements in d3

Tags: html, dom, d3.js

I am trying to create dom that is the following:

```
<g class="geoms">
    <g class="value-labels">
        <rect class="text" width="10" height="10" x="10" y="10"></rect>
        <rect class="text" width="10" height="10" x="10" y="10"></rect>
    </g>
</g>
```

Basically two rectangle elements within a value label and geom class.

I have the following:

```
    @svg = d3.select("body").append("g").attr("class", "geoms")
    @svg.append("g").attr("class", "value-labels")
    @svg.append("rect").attr("class", "text").attr("width", 10).attr("height", 10).attr("x", 10).attr("y", 10)
    @svg.append("rect").attr("class", "text").attr("width", 10).attr("height", 10).attr("x", 10).attr("y", 10)
```

Issue with this code that this is the HTML it generates:

```
<g class="geoms">
    <g class="value-labels"></g>
    <rect class="text" width="10" height="10" x="10" y="10"></rect>         
    <rect class="text" width="10" height="10" x="10" y="10"></rect>  
</g>
```

How do I have the class `value-labels` surround my two rectangles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a reference to the `g` you append and append the `rect`s to it:

```
@svg = d3.select("body").append("g").attr("class", "geoms");
var g = @svg.append("g").attr("class", "value-labels");
g.append("rect").attr("class", "text").attr("width", 10).attr("height", 10).attr("x", 10).attr("y", 10);
g.append("rect").attr("class", "text").attr("width", 10).attr("height", 10).attr("x", 10).attr("y", 10);
```